# What Bayesian priors are diffuse on the log scale?

Tags: r, distributions, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, jags

I am trying to come up with priors for the intercept and coefficients of a Bayesian regression model on the log scale, but I can't get the resulting distribution of the prior to be diffuse once I log transform it. The model attempts to estimate the abundance of several bird species at a number of points, and assumes that the mean abundance of each bird species follows a normal distribution from some grand mean, and there is a random effect on abundance at each point.

Here's a simulation of 100 runs for priors I have tried (in R):

```
### Priors
mean_alpha0 <- rnorm(100, 0, 31) # Prior for log abundance grand mean (sd of 31 = precision of 0.001 in JAGS)
sd_alpha0 <- runif(100, 0, 10) # Prior for standard deviation on log abundance

alpha0 <- rnorm(100, mean_alpha0, sd_alpha0) # Mean log abundance for each species
sd_eps <- runif(100, 0, 10) # Prior for standard deviation of random point effect on log abundance
eps <- rnorm(100, 0, sd_eps) # Random point effect on log abundance 

### Abundance model
loglambda <- alpha0 + eps # Log of expected abundance at each point
N <- rpois(100, exp(loglambda)) # Realized abundance at each point
hist(N)
```

[Distribution of priors after log transformation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0n1BL.png)

As you can see from the histogram, the resulting distribution does not appear diffuse at all, with distribution weight in a range that is completely unrealistic for bird abundance. What are some priors I can use that will create a more diffuse distribution on the log scale for this model? Also, if anybody has resources on good systems for determining priors for transformed scales, please let me know, because what I've found online has been very sparse.

Comment: On what scale is abundance? # of birds? If so, note that centering some prior on zero on the log scale means that half of the prior weight is <1 and half is >1 (on the backtransformed scale), do you want that? Or is it something like birds per square-meter/-mile/-whatever? In any case, the SD on the first prior (31) on the log-scale is an enormous number (I think that's more than the total number of birds on the planet and twice that certainly is), never mind that you then allow variation by up to 10 on top of that. I suspect your priors might be a bit too wide. There's some obvious bounds.

Comment: Since both `mean_alpha0` and `eps` have mean zero, the values of `alpha0 + eps ` can be quite small.